# as3-flash: any way to access all the instances placed in different frames from document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timeline

I have programmed a game using the Flash authoring tool and a document class.
I'm trying to graphically add instances and add functionality in the document class.

Suppose I have a main timeline with 3 frames, each frame reperesents a different level of the game.
In frame 1 I have an instance of the MovieClip class named `tree1` on the stage, 
and in frame 3 I have an instance of the MovieClip class named `tree3` on the stage.

In my document class, after an initial `stop()` command, I want some logic like:

```
tree3.scaleX = tree1.scaleX;
```

But `tree3` is unknown to the runtime since we are not of frame 3 yet.

Any way to access **all the instances on all frames** declared in the authoring tool from the document class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.  As you have said in your question, until the playhead reaches frame three the assets there do not exist.

Comment: thanx a lot. my followup question is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050252/flash-as3-code-execution-order-accessing-a-flash-pro-instance-after-gotoandstop)