# flash-as3 code execution order: accessing a flash pro instance after gotoAndStop()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

*this is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022985/as3-flash-any-way-to-access-all-the-instances-placed-in-different-frames-from-do)*

i have never actually got the flash-actionscript code execution order.

in flash pro i have an instance of a moveiclip on stage in frame one named `tree1` and on frame 3 i have on the stage `tree3`.

in the document class i have this code:

```
stop();
var scaleFactor:Number = tree1.scaleX;
gotoAndStop(3);
tree3.scaleX = scaleFactor;
```

while this works when testing on the desktop, this app will go mobile at the end

is this the correct way to go or should i register for a frameComplete event before accessing instances on a certain frame

Comment: You have a documentClass, but you are using running keyframe on your timeline to execute some code? I think you should post some example, so i can run it in local

Comment: i have no frame-scripts (code on timeline) just symbols i place on the stage that i intend to access with the document class

Comment: the different frames represent different stages of a game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

waiting for Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED is the correct way whenever accessing assets on a timeline

it insures all assets have been created

Answer (score 0):

So, just dont use the Document Class cause you  will need to declare all the scenes from the beginning and will be complicate to manage each scene.

I suggest you to instance a simple MovieClip linked with his own class like the example SceneTree, put it on each Keyframe. You will have more control when you are entering or exiting each frame.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class SceneTree extends MovieClip {


        public function SceneTree() {
            super();
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init);
            this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed);
        }
        protected function Init (event:Event):void{
            trace("added")
        }
        protected function removed (event:Event):void{
            trace("removed")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but that is not for me. all of my code resides in the document class, where everything about the game (like game logic, use interface handling and game settings) is defined. the FLA is for art and art composition only. my question remains: is it necessary to wait for a certain event that assures me all instances in a certain frame have been constructed on stage before i access them? if so - is `frameConstructed` the right one? (i don't want to register `ADDED_TO_STAGE` for each instance)

Comment: With Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED you will access them only when you enter your determinate sceneFrame and the AVM will destroy the rest of elements.